# Need help choosing a name for an interface

Tags: c#, .net, naming

I'm refactoring a number of classes in an application to use interfaces instead of base classes. Here's the interfaces I created so far:

- ICarryable implemented by all Item objects
- IActable implemented by all Actor objects
- IUseable implemented by some Item sub-classes
- IWieldable implemented by some Item sub-classes

You can see the major base-classes are still Item and Actor. These have a common interface in that they both are located on a Map, so they have a Location property. The Map shouldn't care whether the object is an Actor or an Item, so I want to create an interface for it. Here's what the interface would look like

```
public interface IUnnameable {
    event EventHandler<LocationChangedEventArgs> LocationChanged;
    Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

That's no problem, but I can't think of what to call this interface. IMappable comes to mind by seems a bit lame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like an ILocateable. Something whose location you can discover and track.

Answer (score 3):

- ILocatable
- IGeo
- IAmSomewhere
- IIsSomewhere

Edit:

- INoun

Comment: @BCS, seems you've beat Matt to ILocateable. I like it so far, but I'll see if something better comes along before I mark your answer as accepted. I do like ILocateable, though :)

Comment: @Mark Matt got to it first... (sort by oldest)

Comment: Geez it must've been tight though. I don't mind if you mark BCS' as the answer.

Comment: Drats - darn you Matt Hamilton!  I swear I didn't see yours first.  Sounds like there are at least two votes for it.  :-)

Comment: @BCS, You're right, I must have looked at it the other way around. I've already voted you both up though :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [LOLCats](http://icanhascheezburger.com/) notation.

`ICanHasLocation`

or maybe

`IHasLocation`

or the absurd

`ImInYourProgramHavingALocation`

Oh, and by the way - there's at least one [Duck Typing](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx) library for C#, which is a pretty cool concept.

Comment: Neat library, although, I don't believe its needed for this. I think I like IHasLocation the most, but I'm going to choose ILocateable to be consistent with some of the other interface names in my project. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

IWhereYouAtable - Boost mobile

ITwentyable - as in what's your 20 (short for 10-20 - CB slang)

seriously though ILocateable is good.